# Sorting an array of NSIndexPaths

Tags: nsmutablearray, nsindexpath

I have an `NSMutableArray` that contains `NSIndexPath` objects, and I'd like to sort them by their `row`, in ascending order.

What's the shortest/simplest way to do it?

This is what I've tried:

```
[self.selectedIndexPaths sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath1 = obj1;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath2 = obj2;
    return [@(indexPath1.section) compare:@(indexPath2.section)];
}];
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You said that you would like to sort by `row`, yet you compare `section`. Additionally, `section` is `NSInteger`, so you cannot call methods on it.

Modify your code as follows to sort on the `row`:

```
[self.selectedIndexPaths sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSInteger r1 = [obj1 row];
    NSInteger r2 = [obj2 row];
    if (r1 > r2) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    if (r1 < r2) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also use NSSortDescriptors to sort NSIndexPath by the 'row' property.

if `self.selectedIndexPath` is non-mutable:

```
NSSortDescriptor *rowDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"row" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedRows = [self.selectedIndexPaths sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[rowDescriptor]];
```

or if `self.selectedIndexPath` is a `NSMutableArray`, simply:

```
NSSortDescriptor *rowDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"row" ascending:YES];
[self.selectedIndexPaths sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[rowDescriptor]];
```

Simple & short.

Answer (score 8):

For a mutable array:

```
[self.selectedIndexPaths sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

For an immutable array:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [self.selectedIndexPaths sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]
```

Answer (score 3):

In swift:

```
let paths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() as [NSIndexPath]
let sortedArray = paths.sorted {$0.row < $1.row}
```

Comment: Yeah, sorting is much shorter in functional languages.